# How do you convert byte[] -> uint8_t[] without creating issues with JNI?

Tags: java, c++, c, type-conversion, java-native-interface

I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm trying to call a C-based crypto library and supply it a `byte[]` from Java code. It will only work if I change my Java signature to an `int[]`. What gives?

The actual C-library function I'm trying to call is this:

`ecc_verify(const uint8_t p_publicKey[32], const uint8_t p_hash[32], const uint8_t p_signature[32*2]`

My JNI class in Java has this:

`public native static boolean jni_verify(byte[] publicKey, byte[] data, byte[] signature);`

Which results in this header file signature:

`JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_something_eccjni_EccJniExport_jni_1verify
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jbyteArray, jbyteArray, jbyteArray);`

And my C implementation is:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_something_eccjni_EccJniExport_ecdsa_1verify
(JNIEnv *jniEnv, jclass clazz, jbyteArray publicKeyArray, jbyteArray dataArray, jbyteArray signatureArray){
    jboolean isCopy;

    jbyte* publicKey = (*jniEnv)->GetByteArrayElements(jniEnv, publicKeyArray, &isCopy);
    jbyte* data = (*jniEnv)->GetByteArrayElements(jniEnv, dataArray, &isCopy);
    jbyte* signature = (*jniEnv)->GetByteArrayElements(jniEnv, signatureArray, &isCopy);

    int result = ecdsa_verify((uint8_t *) publicKey,(uint8_t *) data,(uint8_t *) signature);

    (*jniEnv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jniEnv, publicKeyArray, publicKey, JNI_ABORT);
    (*jniEnv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jniEnv, dataArray, data, JNI_ABORT);
    (*jniEnv)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(jniEnv, signatureArray, signature, JNI_ABORT);

    return result;
}
```

This *never* works. This often results in a message:

```
java(9966,0x7000012c8000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb7a0614758: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

However, if I change everything to this, it works:

`public native static boolean ecdsa_verify(int[] publicKey, int[] data, int[] signature);`

`JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_something_eccjni_EccJniExport_ecdsa_1verify
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jintArray, jintArray, jintArray);`

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_something_eccjni_EccJniExport_ecdsa_1verify
(JNIEnv *jniEnv, jclass clazz, jintArray publicKeyArray, jintArray dataArray, jintArray signatureArray){
    jboolean isCopy;

    jint* publicKey = (*jniEnv)->GetIntArrayElements(jniEnv, publicKeyArray, &isCopy);
    jint* data = (*jniEnv)->GetIntArrayElements(jniEnv, dataArray, &isCopy);
    jint* signature = (*jniEnv)->GetIntArrayElements(jniEnv, signatureArray, &isCopy);

    int result = ecdsa_verify((uint8_t *) publicKey,(uint8_t *) data,(uint8_t *) signature);

    (*jniEnv)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(jniEnv, publicKeyArray, publicKey, JNI_ABORT);
    (*jniEnv)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(jniEnv, dataArray, data, JNI_ABORT);
    (*jniEnv)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(jniEnv, signatureArray, signature, JNI_ABORT);

    return result;
}
```

What's going on?

## EDIT

Here's the Calling Java:

```
    System.load(EccJni.class.getResource("/EccJniExport.jnilib").getFile());
    byte[] publicKey = new byte[32];
    byte[] privateKey = new byte[32];
    EccJniExport.ecc_make_key(publicKey, privateKey);

    byte[] data = new byte[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = (byte) i;
    }
    byte[] signature = new byte[32];
    EccJniExport.ecdsa_sign(privateKey, data, signature);

    System.out.println("result:" + EccJniExport.ecdsa_verify(publicKey, data, signature));
```

Again, if you change the `byte[]` to `int[]` everything works peachy

Comment: Your "C implementation" doesn't look like C to me...

Comment: Your `byte[]` implementation looks fine to me, provided the `byte[]` arrays are allocated correctly. `byte` is the correct type to use for `uint8_t` data. Is your Java code allocating the `byte[]` arrays that it passes to `jni_verify()`?

Comment: Yes, they are not null. The values are initialized and filled.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing the actual Java code

Comment: You are not allocating enough bytes for the `p_signature` parameter.  It expects `32*2` bytes, but you are allocating only 32 bytes.

Comment: AGH! That's it! Thank you! Please add that as an answer so I can accept

Comment: An answer has been posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You are not allocating enough bytes for the `signature` array.

The C function expects `32*2` bytes for that parameter, but your Java code is allocating `32` bytes instead.

That explains why the code works when you use an `int[]` array instead of a `byte[]` array.  You would be allocating `32*4` bytes in that situation.